# Dlookup Run-time error '3075': Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I get:
[image: Run-time error 3075]

My code:

```vb
Private Sub CustomerID()
    
    Dim ID As Long
    Dim frm As Access.Form
    Set frm = Forms!Frm_JobTicket

    'Look up Customer Name and insert corresponding ID from Qry_CustomerID
    ID = DLookup("Customer_ID", "Qry_CustomerID", "Customer_Name = " & frm("Customer_Name"))
    
    Syteline_Customer_ID = ID

End Sub
```

I tried to set a form control [Syteline_Customer_ID] = to the Dlookup, but it gave me this same error.

This is my attempt at working around it. [Syteline_Customer_ID] is a text box on Frm_JobTicket.
Qry_CustomerID pulls in 2 fields from Tbl_MasterCustomerList. That table's structure is as follows:

> Customer_ID - Number (Integer)
> Customer_Name - Short Text
> Billing_Address - Short Text
> Contact_Person - Short Text
> CP_Email - Short Text
> CP_Phone - Short Text

I checked Qry_CustomerID is not spelled wrong, and is not missing an underscore, that's just my naming convention.
I tried changing it to just Query1 to call it.

Comment: Simply enclose the form control concatenation with single quotes: `"Customer_Name = '" & frm("Customer_Name") & "'"`

Comment: @Parfait Thanks so much, that worked like a charm! I cannot believe it was that easy - I was genuinely stumped on this one. Guess I need to work on my understand of syntax. If you would like to submit this as the answer I can mark it so you get credit, otherwise tomorrow I will respond to myself and answer it for future people having the same troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text fields require quote enclosure around literal values. Without quotes, the Access engine assumes you are referencing another field by that literal value. And in your case the space in the name value raised a syntax error. Therefore, in concatenating the form control value, simply enclose it with single quotes:

```vb
"Customer_Name = '" & frm("Customer_Name") & "'"
```

Actually, you do not even need any concatenation as `DLookUp` can read open form fields with absolute referencing:

```vb
"Customer_Name = Forms!Frm_JobTicket!Customer_Name"
```